# how node makes a rest request

Tags: node.js, rest

I am having weird firewall issues at my workplace, where i can make rest requests using paw, curl or another rest client, but when i try to make a rest request using node i get a timeout.

When i mention this to IT helpdesk guys, they always look at me baffled and asked, "what is node doing then?".

So my question is why would a request work when using a rest client but not with node.js what is node doing under the hood?

Also, this occurs with two node frameworks, wreck and connect, my node version is v7.5.0.

EDIT:
Also the response from both frameworks, is always undefined, so i cant see if there is any changes made by the frameworks/node when making the request.

Comment: Look in the logs and compare the requests. They might for sure be different (different headers, parameters, ...). I do not think node uses different protocols or anything under the hood

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have and I havent found nothing:(. If i am on one of the work wifi, this problem exists with just one environment, but if i change wifi it works fine. i am really puzzled with what is going on, i keep thinking that maybe node puts some sort of signature (like header, something) on the requests that some stupid firewall rule is blocking, but i cant find nothing.

Comment: might be a CORS issue